# android device lenovo build number A269i_so16_130927 is not install android application "Radiud edu" from google play store

Tags: android

My application is running perfectly in my local device and install perfectly in google app store but when i am going to install this same application from google app store,i am getting this error "not able to download for this device" .This issue is generated only in Lenovo(build number  A269i_so16_130927) mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is with the old apk, if you have any old application copy in the device please uninstall that and try

Comment: actually at google play store that application not showing.name as"Radius edu"

Comment: given error This device is isn't compatible with this version.But this same apk is perfectly run on this same device